# Oracle naming not null constraints?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus, constraints

I was just wondering if it is possible to name your `NOT NULL` constraints on columns? Like you can with a check constraint.

Thanks,
Alex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
create table table1(column1 number constraint column1_not_null not null);
```